# html 5 tag not supporting on below ie9?

Tags: html

i just visited apple.com and they use some html5 tag like nav. it is working in all broswer but i i try to test html5 code it is not working in ie8 and ie7. i am not getting what is the problem how apple site working in all browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
<head xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>html 5</title>
<style>
#header { margin:0 auto; width:980px; overflow:hidden; border:solid 1px #F00}
</style>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
<header id="header">adfadf</header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should read more about what HTML5 is, what browsers support it, and how to adjust to older browsers. http://www.quirksmode.org/ http://caniuse.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

older versions of IE don't treat the new HTML5 elements like header, nav, article, footer, address as "unknown" elements.

You can simply introduce the new elements to the old IE family members by using a simple JavaScript approach:

```
document.createElement("article");  
document.createElement("footer");  
document.createElement("header");  
document.createElement("hgroup");  
document.createElement("nav");
```

Check out the article [HTML5 Shiv](http://ejohn.org/blog/html5-shiv/) and e.g. the [modernizr framewoerk](http://www.modernizr.com/)

HTH,

--hennson

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this script to get html5 work: http://www.modernizr.com/download/

Answer (score 0):

IE8 and IE7 aren't HTML5 compliant, so your code won't execute. I'm guessing the Apple site has caveats to test which browser you are using . Any control in particular you're looking to use?

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean by “not working in ie8 and ie7”. I see you’ve got HTML5shiv in there — that should make IE recognise your `<header>` element at least. Is the red border showing up at least?

Bear in mind that IE (just like older versions of Firefox) won’t apply any default styles to these elements, so you’ll need to add those too, e.g.

```
header {
    display: block;
}
```

Reset stylesheets like Eric Meyer’s add this CSS for you:

- http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: @amit: does anything change in IE 7 if you put html5shiv back in?